# add record to combobox binded to datasource

Tags: extjs, ext.net

I have a combobox binded to a datasource here is the sample :

```
<ext:Store runat="server" ID="StoreBoitier">
        <Model>
            <ext:Model ID="Model5" runat="server">
                <Fields>
                    <ext:ModelField Name="Text" runat="server"></ext:ModelField>
                    <ext:ModelField Name="Value" runat="server"></ext:ModelField>
                </Fields>
            </ext:Model>
        </Model>
</ext:Store>

 <ext:ComboBox runat="server" ID="ComboBoxBoitier" StoreID="StoreBoitier" DisplayField="Text" ValueField="Value" EmptyText="Boitier" Visible="true" Editable="false">

 </ext:ComboBox>
```

when i try to add a new record to the combobox even with directevent :

```
        Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>(2);
        values.Add("Text", "/Text0");
        values.Add("Value", "0");

        this.ComboBoxBoitier.InsertRecord(1, values);
        this.ComboBoxBoitier.SelectedItems.Clear();
        this.ComboBoxBoitier.SelectedItems.Add(new Ext.Net.ListItem { Value = "0" });
        this.ComboBoxBoitier.UpdateSelectedItems();
```

or with listener :

```
#{ComboBoxBoitier}.insertRecord(1, { Text  : 'Text1', 
                                        Value : 1 
                                    });
```

it never works the first time until i click two times , i'm turning crazy since two days pleaaaase help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add QueryMode="Local" for the ComboBox.

I would recommend to read the ExtJS docs article about the [queryMode](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-queryMode) option. There is local data in your scenario, so, QueryMode should be Local, but it is Remote by default.

Comment: really you are THE BOSS !!! it works thank's a looot but please can you tell what changes when i turned queryMode to local and what were wrong before . thanks a loooot !!!

Comment: Glad it helped you! As for explanation, I've edited the answer.